# Options in CJuiDatePicker in yii

Tags: php, yii

What is the difference between the 'defaultOptions' and 'options' in datepicker widgets in yii?

> $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(...
>   'defaultOptions' => array(...)
>   'options'=>array(...)
>   )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the [Yii documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDatePicker) ...

**[defaultOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDatePicker#defaultOptions-detail)**
The default options called just one time per request. This options will alter every other CJuiDatePicker instance in the page. It has to be set at the first call of CJuiDatePicker widget in the request.

**[options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiWidget#options-detail)**
The initial JavaScript options that should be passed to the JUI plugin.

**[htmlOption](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiWidget#htmlOptions-detail)**
The HTML attributes that should be rendered in the HTML tag representing the JUI widget.

Comment: Hi jurik, if i want to add language, button image then, where to place it?

Comment: If you want add a background image to your button via css you should use the third, yet not mentioned, option. It is called [htmlOption](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiWidget#htmlOptions-detail) and there you could pass CSS or a css class. I added it to my answer.